# Downsample data preserving regions with high curvature

Tags: matlab, plot, resampling

I want to do the following:

- Plot some two-dimensional data which uses way too many mesh points.
- Reduce the number of mesh points by a factor of three.
- In this plot are some regions with high curvature and some with low curvature, and I cannot remove the data in high-curvature regions but I can live without some data in low-curvature regions.

Is there any simple way to do this?

I tried the MATLAB functions `downsample`, `interpolate`, `resample`, `interp`, `interp1`, and `upfirdn` but none of them seems to solve my problem since they all have something to do with signal and frequency, but my problem is not of this kind.

Comment: It would be useful if you added an example data set or function with this behaviour, so we can easily suggest solutions (a [MCVE]). Do you have a function (i.e. which you could differentiate) or just discrete data points?